# How to use Z3 on a 32bit windows xp

Tags: z3

Recently, I tried to use z3 on a 32bit windows xp, and when I load z3dll using java api, it threw error message as follow:
WindowsError: [Error 998] Invalid access to memory location.

I noticed that, Z3 dosen't support Windows XP because of thread-local storage. I wonder is there any way to adapt z3 to windows xp.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way, but it may involve considerable effort. Thread-local storage is used to track memory allocation sizes per thread which would otherwise have to be locked, I.e. It will be much slower. If you don't need any multi-threading you could of course just remove that part (see memory_manager.cpp). There's no guarantee that there aren't any other XP specific problems after that though; we don't test anything on XP anymore.

Also note that support for XP has ended globally (all of Microsoft, not just Z3).

Comment: Thanks. what is the considerable effort you mentioned, could you please give me some guide? And , another way by removing the multi-threading part, how can I do this job?

Comment: Just remove the thread-local declarations in memory_manager.cpp/.h, that should get you most of the way. You may also have to configure the build with --no-omp to disable openmp. But, remember that any concurrency will throw segfaults, e.g. You may have to disable any concurrent garbage collection that your target language uses.

Answer (score 0):

I just disabled the if statement for the macro of '_USE_THREAD_LOCAL' in memory_manager.cpp and rebuild. It worked and could be loaded on windows xp now.